# Can we divide by $x$ when doing U-Substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

I was watching a Professor Leonard on [U-substitution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiBD9aI69C8) and he's dividing by $x$ all the time but doesn't that assume that $x \neq 0$ (even though there's no reason why it can't be $0$}

Although it makes the simplification kinda fun because you can see things cancel, is this actually correct? He seems to note at 11:30 that it's different than how others teach and I'm wondering if that's because his way might fail at times?

This is the first example he gives, transforming $\int \left(x^2+1\right)^{50} \cdot 2x dx $ into $\int u^{50} \cdot 2x \frac{du}{2x}$ through this subtitution:

\begin{align*}
u = & \ x^2-1 \\
\\
du= & \ 2x dx \\
\\
\frac{du}{dx}= & \ \frac{2x dx}{dx} \\
\\
\frac{du}{2x} = & \ dx \\
\\
\end{align*}

In his substitution, he just cancels the $2x$'s but it seems like he's assuming $x\neq 0$?

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just note that since $2xdx=du,$ then the first integral becomes $$\int u^{50}du$$ immediately. There's no need to divide anything.